# Android xmpp smack 4.1 processMessage

Tags: android, xmpp

Столкнулся с такой проблемой! На сервере установлен OpenFire 3.10.2 на android девайсе добавленна библиотека smack 4.1.x (перепробовал много вариантов). Когда тестировал использовал клиент для mac os под названием Adium. При пересылке сообщений с android устройства на клиент на mac os и наоборот все сообщения доставляются без проблем, но при тестировании на двух android устройствах, сообщения в режиме отладки доходят до получателей, но не вызывается `public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message)`. Подскажите, как справиться с такой проблемой?

Comment: Проблемма решилась исполльзуя совет по этой ссылке:
https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/54377

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1):

Проблемма решилась исполльзуя совет по этой ссылке: https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/54377

```
ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection).addChatListener(new ChatManagerListener() {
            @Override
            public void chatCreated(Chat chat, boolean createdLocally) {
                chat.addMessageListener(new ChatMessageListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
                        if (message.getType() == Message.Type.chat || message.getType() == Message.Type.normal) {
                            if(message.getBody()!=null) {
                              Toast.makeText(this,message.getFrom() + " : " + message.getBody(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```